# How do I get the highest value in a row in excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking to compare the value of the max score of a group of people, format is as follows:

```
date            user1   user2   user3
06/07/2011      123     112     244
```

How do I determine which of values on the row is the highest? Eg, I would like to pull 244 from this row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the max-function?

```
=MAX(b1:d1)
```

Comment: LAME. I didn't realize it was this easy, I think I just googled badly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the max function in whatever cell you want it in: `=Max(A2:A4)`